# Disable hover opacity effect for one particular image

Tags: css, hover, opacity

I have added a hover opacity effect on my images, as follows:

```
img {
  opacity: 1.0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=1.0); 
}
img:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0.6); 
}
```

I want to disable this hover effect completely for one particular image.

How could this be achieved?

Comment: You can give that page an ID and disable it in your css.

Comment: FYI, the extra `filter` is not needed, it's for very old IE, [read more](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/).

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID to the image, and change the CSS to the following:

```
img{
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=1.0); 
}

img:not(#id):hover{
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0.6); 
}
```

With the `:not()` selector, you can exclude certain elements

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to the Element you don't want this effect on

```css
img {
  opacity: 1.0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=1.0);
}
img:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0.6);
}
img.nohover:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=1.0);
}
```

```html
<img class="nohover" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Bogenverzahnung.JPG" />
```